# Как объяснить браузеру какой input является логином, а какой нет?

Tags: html5, браузер, html-form

Есть форма регистрации, в ней 4 поля ввода (имя, почта (используется как логин), пароль, повтор пароля). Я бы хотел что-бы браузер запоминал как логин почту, а не имя.

```html
<form id="registration-form" action="media/php/reg-user.php" method="post">
  <input placeholder="E-mail" type="email" name="login" class="form__input">
  <input placeholder="Имя" type="text" name="name" class="form__input">
  <input placeholder="Пароль" type="password" name="password" class="form__input">
  <input placeholder="Повтор пароля" type="password" name="password-repeat" class="form__input">
  <button type="submit" id="form__button-submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Попробуйте для первого поля указать `name="email"`

Comment: У вас на странице авторизации, у `input` присутствует `type="email"`?

Comment: Ничего не понял. 4 поля отправляются для обработки в скрипт media/php/reg-user.php. Именно этот скрипт получает значения полей и обрабатывает данные. В нём и напишите, какое из полей расцениваете как логин. При чём здесь браузер? Он вообще не обязан что-то "запоминать".

Comment: Quazimorda, имелся введу автофил браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms) о том, как делать формы дружные с автокомплитом. А вот [тут](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands) подробности с примерами. Я бы попробовал что-то вроде:

```
  <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="username">
   <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
   <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
   <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
  </form>
```

Еще там есть хороший пример логина в два этапа, он мне нравится больше других:

Email First Sign-in Flow:

Collect the email:

```
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="username">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
</form>
```

Then collect the password, but include the email as the value of a hidden form field:

```
<style>
  #emailfield { display: none; }
</style>
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
  <input id="emailfield" type="text" value="me@example.test" autocomplete="username">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отдайте имя login нужному полю
Или как вариант autocomplete="on"

Comment: Спасибо. Попробовал, проблемы не решает. Браузер усердно запоминает не то поле

Answer (score 0):

Опять же, не уверен, правильно ли я вас понимаю, вам уже советовали выше autocomplete. Решит ли это проблему, но я бы доработал форму так:

```html
    <form id="registration-form" action="media/php/reg-user.php" method="post" autocomplete="on">
      <input placeholder="E-mail" type="email" name="login" class="form__input">
      <input placeholder="Имя" type="text" name="name" class="form__input">
      <input placeholder="Пароль" type="password" name="password" class="form__input">
      <input placeholder="Повтор пароля" type="password" name="password-repeat" class="form__input">
      <button type="submit" id="form__button-submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
```

Не уверен, что в нужных полях будут подставляться нужные значения.